# Add more elements in CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop something where I need this requirement, I tried a couple of things, but not able to do it.

There is one style - **A**:

```
.someClass {
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

now I want to add `margin` also in same class like - **B**:

```
.someClass {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Now I need both, `padding` and `margin`. The thing is I can't modify **A** as it set by some third party JS, which doesn't reside locally.

So, is there any way I can achieve this by **Pure CSS or JS (NO Jquery)**

Comment: do you need to change the style class declaration for further uses, or it's ok if you just change all already existing elements of that class?

Comment: I'm confused. The code as you give it will already assign `padding-right` and `margin-left` to elements with the class `.someClass`. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is one style - A:

```
.someClass {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

No, that is not a "style". That is a "rule". It says to apply `padding-right` to elements with the `someClass` class.

Now you add another rule:

```
.someClass {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

That says to apply `margin-left` to elements with the `someClass` class.

Together the two rules do exactly what you want. The key point is that CSS will apply **all** rules whose "selectors" (here, the `.someClass` part) match the element in question. If the two rules contain the same properties, then there are ways (involving concepts such as "precedence" and "specificity") in which CSS will choose which one to apply, but that is not the case here, so both `padding-right` and `margin-left` will be applied to elements with the `someClass` class.

Comment: so it will not overwrite the previous one? correct?

Comment: No, it will not overwrite/override. That is the meaning of the concept of "cascade", which is the "C" in "CSS".

Answer (score 1):

You can put both margin and padding into the element at once:

```
.someClass{
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Also if the margin or anything else is set by like you said third party JS you can Override it in CSS by adding: !important  so your code would look like this:

```
.someClass{
margin: 10px !important;
padding: 10px !important;
}
```

According to your question you need only padding to override.
Hope i understood your Question and could help.